# I want to see my design that´s in a expander XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

How can i see my design that´s **in** the expander in design view? I use VS2015.

```
<Grid Grid.Row="2" Height="30" Background="{StaticResource HeaderBackground}" Margin="5">
        <TextBlock Foreground="{StaticResource HeaderText}" Text="Old Events" FontSize="15" Margin="10,0,0,0" />


        <Expander HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                  IsExpanded="True"
                  ExpandDirection="Down"
                  FlowDirection="RightToLeft">

            <Grid FlowDirection="LeftToRight">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid Grid.Row="0" Margin="5,0,5,0" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions >
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="6"" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="56"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="18"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="106" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15"/>
                            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,2"/>
                        </Style>
                    </Grid.Resources>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Id" Margin="0,4,0,6" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Text="Event" Margin="0,4,0,6"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4" Text="Namn" Margin="0,4,0,6"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="5" Text="Tidpunkt" Margin="0,4,0,6"/>
                    <Border Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" BorderBrush="Black"/>

                    <ListView Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="OldEventsListView" Style="{x:Null}" ItemsSource="{Binding NotificationEvents}" BorderThickness="0" Width="488" Height="150" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,-2,-150" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                        <ListView.Resources>
                            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:NotificationEventViewModel+NotificationEvent}">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="B" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="B"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="C"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                    <Grid.Resources>
                                        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                            <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
                                            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                                            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                                        </Style>
                                    </Grid.Resources>
                                    <Border BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" BorderBrush="LightGray" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Margin="0,5,0,5" />
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Id}" />
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Event}"/>
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding TimeStamp}"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.Resources>
                    </ListView>
                </Grid>
                <Grid Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                    <Button Background="MidnightBlue" Foreground="White" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Medium" Click="GetTenMoreEvents">
                        <Button.Content>
                            <TextBlock Text="10 till"/>
                        </Button.Content>
                    </Button>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Expander>
    </Grid>
```

I thought that `IsExpanded="True"` would do the thing. But it´s no different. In the picture you can see my design. Here i want my expander to show my "Old Events" listview. So  the problem is in Visual Studio, not when I fire my program. 
[image: I want too see whats in the Old events expander]

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I tried your code and the `expander` expands in `design mode` even without the `IsExpanded` property. I think the cause is not within the code you posted..

Comment: and this `<ColumnDefinition Width="6"" />` have two quotation marks

Comment: Oh okey @Paolo Go. I will try to find something and post it here. 
The ``<ColumnDefinition Width="6"" />`` was just a typo here, not in my real code but thanks for noties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now found the solution for my problem. 
I had done wrong with my `<Grid>` and added one too many.

```
<Grid Grid.Row="2" Height="30" Background="{StaticResource HeaderBackground}" Margin="5">
        <TextBlock Foreground="{StaticResource HeaderText}" Text="Old Events" FontSize="15" Margin="10,0,0,0" />
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="3">
        <Expander HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                  ExpandDirection="Down">
            <Grid Margin="5,0,5,0" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions >
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="80" SharedSizeGroup="A" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="150" SharedSizeGroup="B" />
                    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="B" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="106" SharedSizeGroup="C" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15"/>
                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,2"/>
                    </Style>
                </Grid.Resources>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Id" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="Event"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Text="Name"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Text="Timestamp"/>
                    <Border Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" BorderBrush="Black"/>

                <ListView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" x:Name="OldEventsListView" Style="{x:Null}" ItemsSource="{Binding NotificationEvents}" BorderThickness="0" Width="488" Height="150" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                    <ListView.Resources>
                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:NotificationEvent}">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="B" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="B"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="C"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <Grid.Resources>
                                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
                                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                                        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                                    </Style>
                                </Grid.Resources>
                                <Border BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" BorderBrush="LightGray" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Margin="0,5,0,5" />
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Id}" />
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Event}"/>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding TimeStamp}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.Resources>
                </ListView>
                <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="MidnightBlue" Foreground="White" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Medium" Click="GetTenMoreEvents">
                    <Button.Content>
                        <TextBlock Text="10 till"/>
                    </Button.Content>
                </Button>
            </Grid>
        </Expander>
    </Grid>
```

So I remove `<Grid Grid.Row="0" Margin="5,0,5,0" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">` because this was totally wrong. Now the expander works as a charm.